# What are the pros and cons of a straight wing plane?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing

I need this asap for my folio... Much appreciated. I'm doing a research section on my folio and I need to know the pros and cons for a straight wing in general. Everywhere I've searched doesn't seem to have the question above and is making it very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean unswept vs swept-back wings.

Pro:

- Easy to manufacture
- More efficient at low-subsonic speeds

Con:

- Unstable at transsonic and supersonic speeds (see [Mach tuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_tuck))

More details about wing sweep (including forward sweep) that should answer your question: [Swept wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swept_wing)